# How to use SensorEventListener to determine direction phone is facing relative to magnetic north

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

I'm trying to write a class that implements `SensorEventListener` to determine the direction the phone's camera is facing (Galaxy S3), in degrees east from magnetic north. Here are the sensors I'm using:

```
  public void start()
  {
    mManager.registerListener(this, mManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    mManager.registerListener(this, mManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),  SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
  }
```

I believe I'm looking for the azimuth, which is stored in `mOrientation[0]` after calling `SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, mOrientation);`.

However, when I do that, the result seems to be rotation around gravity and not rotation from magnetic north. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `remapCoordinateSystem(inR, AXIS_X, AXIS_Z, outR);` before calling `getOrientation` to get the direction of back camera. The `azimuth` is then the direction with respect to magnetic north.
This amount to projecting the minus Z-axis of the device coordinate system to the world East-North plane and then calculate the angle between the projected vector and the North axis.